# auto number problem

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question about the auto number, for example, I insert a record into the field "Id" in table "products". I input 3 fields "id" is 1.2, and 3. when I remove fied into 3, then I input the updated field again is 4, not 3. how so recorded is 3 instead of 4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by design. An identifier that has been used once must never, ever be used for another record. It could cause data corruption issues if there are relationships between tables - records could suddenly be pointing to a completely unrelated record in the original table.

Reference: [3.6.9. Using AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: You should think of the auto_number fields as a pointer reference and nothing more. It's unique and should never be duplicated or overwritten unless you truly want it to be pointed to by another reference which rarely happens. you typically update FOREIGN keys, not the PRIMARY ones

Answer (score 0):

You may run the query: `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1`

That will reset the beginning position of Auto-increment, hence when you insert the record again, it will take id 3.

You may find this [link](http://www.liewcf.com/mysql-reset-auto-increament-number-115/) useful. It's very short and coherent.

Comment: This is a really bad idea for reasons that @Pekka mentioned above. You lose all data integrity if you do this.

Comment: @seth.vargo: Yeah, as Pekka point out, this is not a good practice. But it's possible. I think the asker understand his/her database schema, and may ask this question because of curiosity.

Comment: for the record, I wasn't the person who downvoted you and I'll upvote to offset because you DID answer his question